# Javascript - Function not found?! called from onClick, and function is in same page

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a really weird and confusing error.

Here is my code:

```
{if="$pjax === false"}{include="header"}{/if}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function clickclear(thisfield, defaulttext) {
            if (thisfield.value == defaulttext) {
                thisfield.value = "";
            }
        }
        function clickrecall(thisfield, defaulttext) {
            if (thisfield.value == "") {
                thisfield.value = defaulttext;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<form action='./login' method='post' name='form'>
<ul class="form">
    <li><input type="text" name="username" value="Username" id="username" onclick="clickclear(this, 'Username')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Username')"  /></li>
    <li><input type="password" name="password" value="Password" id="password" onclick="clickclear(this, 'Password')" onblur="clickrecall(this,'Password')" /></li>
    <li><span style='display:block;height:27px;float:left;line-height:27px;'>Remember Me</span> <div id='itoggle' style='float:right;'><input type="checkbox" id="remember" class='itoggle' /></div><div class='clearfix'></div></li>
</ul>
</form>
<a href="javascript: form.submit()" class="button white">Login</a>
{if="$pjax === false"}{include="footer"}{/if}
```

You can see there are two functions, `clickclear` and `clickrecall`. These get called from the form inputs on `onClick` and `onBlur`. However, when I run them, I get these javascript errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: clickclear is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: clickrecall is not defined

Any ideas? I know it's probably something really simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: There's no reason to wrap your functions inside document.ready.

Comment: It's because the functions are ONLY available inside the .ready() function: they're private functions to that function.

Comment: It still gave the same error when i didnt use document.ready

Comment: please restrict your code to what the browser gets - not the templated source!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your functions are in the `.ready()` callback. These are not visible from the global scope (which is good).

It's better using jQuery's event attachment methods like `.on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //your code
    function clickclear(){...}
    function clickrecall(){...}

    //the handlers
    $('#username').on('click',function(){ //bind click handler
        clickclear(this,'Username');      //things to do on click
    }).on('blur',function(){              //chain blur handler
        clickrecall(this,'Username');     //things to do on blur
    });

    $('#password').on('click',function(){ //bind click handler
        clickclear(this,'Password');      //things to do on click
    }).on('blur',function(){              //chain blur handler
        clickrecall(this,'Password');     //things to do on blur
    });

    ...other handlers...

});
```

And a side note, there is a `placeholder` attribute for Chrome, which acts like placeholder text:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" />
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. but it seems like quite a large quantitiy of code for such a small feature, this is for a mobile website so i want to restrict as much code as possible. I think i may be able to impliment this idea into a smaller code for all the inputs. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: And yeah i know about placeholder :P but although its a mobile site, i like to keep code similar to work in IE and such

Comment: @DanSpiteri you can minify your code for production and it is better to do it this way because of "separation of concerns" (separate HTML, CSS and JS from each other) for clean code.